# Update NumericUpDown.Maximum from corresponding txt.text control using for each loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

As newbie in VBA.net i want to solve following.

I have a form with 38 text controls in 4 groupboxes. These get filled by clicking a row in a datagridview. I have 38 corresponding NUD's where i want the maximum to be equal to its corresponding text.
A 'pair' is always in one of the 4 groupboxes. Besides that there are also textboxes on the form itself to control the DGV.

I have a naming convention that makes it possible to match them easily . NUDGeel corresponds with txtGeel , NUDRood with TxtRood, NUDGroen with txtGroen etc et

Now that update is easily done if you do them one by one

```
NUDGeel.maximum = txtGeel.text
NUDRood.maximum = txtRood.text
etc
```

What i want to achieve is that this gets done in a for each loop. (Order to prevent me typing this 38 times (and also just to 'understand' it)

I can figure out how to start the loop

```
Dim c As Control
For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "NumericUpDown" Then
    'do some magic
    End If
Next
```

I have tried to search for the magic code, and i guess from research it is pretty simple, i just donot get it .

Anyone with an idea how to fix ?

Answer (score 1):

```vb
For Each tb In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
    Dim nud = DirectCast(Controls(tb.Name.Replace("txt", "NUD")), NumericUpDown)

    If nud IsNot Nothing Then
        nud.Maximum = CDec(tb.Text)
    End If
Next
```

You don't need the `If` statement if there are no other `TextBoxes` on the form besides those with corresponding `NumericUpDowns`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I will test this . But i will have to add an IF as there are other Textboxes indeed (to manage the DataGridSelection) . My plan is to add a TAG in the textbox and test on that. On the other hand i have the relevant textboxes in 4 different groupboxes (Layout wise) . Any suggestion on what solution is best ?

Comment: @WalterWouters, please update your question and specify exactly where the `TextBoxes` and corresponding `NumericUpDowns` are.

Comment: The corresponding NUD and TextBoxes are always in the same groupbox. So i have 4 groupboxes containing x 'pairs' of NUD and corresponding TextBoxes. The other textboxes to control the DGV are outside the groupboexes. I hope this made it clear ?

Comment: @WalterWouters, you missed the part where I said *"please update your question"*. We should be answering the question as asked. No one should have to read comments on an answer to understand the question.

Comment: Thanks John, I think it made it a little bit more clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub SetMaximum()
    Dim controlNames() As String = {
        "Geel", "Rood", "Name1", "Name2", ' list all the names of your controls here excluding NUD/txt
        }

    For Each controlName As String In controlNames
        CType(Me.Controls("NUD" & controlName),NumericUpDown).Maximum = CType(Me.Controls("txt" & controlName),TextBox).Text
    Next
End Sub
```

This assumes that all the controls are not inside any containers. If they are, you must use the container (panel, groupbox, etc) instead of Me.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In my understanding this however requires that all controls are 'listed' whereas the other solution is more 'dynamic' and easier to reuse in another context.

Comment: Hi, justed tested and working.  Would be ideal if adding the names was not required.:)